How to fix recommendationsSDK error on PDP
On our pdp's we get this error:
Error: Script error for "recommendationsSDK", needed by: Magento_ProductRecommendationsLayout/js/recsFetcher

I tried to manually add <script src="https://magento-recs-sdk.adobe.net/v1/index.js"></script> in order to fix it, but this didnt work. The recommendationsSDK is part of magento commerce (enterprise) edition. This error also shows when theme is set back to the default Luma theme
